# How to iterate a list of words, and print all words not containing any char of a substring?

Tags: python

The goal is to print out all words from the text file which do not contain any of the characters in the substring.

My current solution is:

```
words = open('words.txt')

def avoids(fin, letter):
    for line in fin:
        for char in letter:
            if char in line:
                break
            print(line.strip())

avoids(words, 'abo')
```

The output is:
bdellium
bdelliums
be
bebeeru
bebeerus
beblood
beblooded
beblooding
bebloods

It avoids all words with **a** but still prints all words with **b** and **o**. I know that my mistake has to do something with the break out of the second loop, but I'm just not able to spot it.

Comment: [mre] would include a list of words instead of using a file that we don't have (and don't want).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list comprehension that checks, for every letter, if it's in the word. If there are no True values in the list, keep the word.

```
def avoids(fin, letters):
    to_keep = []
    
    for line in fin:
        if not any(l for l in letters if l in line):
            to_keep.append(line)
            
    return to_keep

avoids(['google', 'stackoverflow', 'reddit'], 'abc')

>>> ['google', 'reddit']
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to print the line when you know that it contains none of the letters.

One solution is to use else after the inner loop:

```py
    words = open('words.txt')   
                                                                                    
    def avoids(fin, letter):                      
        for line in fin:
            for char in letter:
                if char in line:
                    break                                            
            else:
                print(line.strip()) 
                                                                            
    avoids(words, 'abo')
```

Another solution is to use the any function:

```py
    words = open('words.txt')   
                                                                                    
    def avoids(fin, letter):                      
        for line in fin:                                            
            if not any(char in line for char in letter):
                print(line.strip()) 
                                                                            
    avoids(words, 'abo')
```

Comment: wow, I did not know that the else statement could be placed outside the loop. Thank you a lot!